# Calling Methods in Main Class and Other Class Differences in Java

Tags: java

I have 3 classes, Mainn, ReadFile, and Entry.

ReadFile is basically my class that does all file i/o stuff.

How come I am able to access ReadFile in my Mainn class just fine, but
when I try to access it in Entry "e.openFile()" i get an error that says identifier expected.

I know this can be fixed by making an overloaded method openFile() in Entry but why is this needed in Entry, but not in the main class Mainn?

```
package homework6;

public class mainn {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
        r.openFile();
        //r.readFile();
        r.skipFirst();
        String x[] = r.getData();
        String y[] = r.getData();
        String z[] = r.getData();

        System.out.println(x[0] + "," + x[1]);
        System.out.println(y[0] + "," + y[1]);
        System.out.println(z[0] + "," + z[1]);

        r.closeFile();
    }
}
```

ReadFile:

```
package homework6;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFile {
    Scanner x = null;

    public void openFile(){
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(
                    "C:\\Users\\Rohan Vidyarthi\\workspace\\Data.csv"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found error");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        while (x.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(x.nextLine());
    }

    public void skipFirst(){
        x.nextLine();
    }

    public String[] getData(){ //returns String[] with Date and ADJ Close
        String[] temp;
        String[] out = new String[2]; 
        temp = (x.nextLine()).split(",");
        out[0] = temp[0];
        out[1] = temp[6];
        return out;
    }

    public boolean checker(){
        return x.hasNextLine();
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}
```

class Entry:

```
package homework6;

public class Entry extends ReadFile{
    ReadFile e = new ReadFile();
    e.openFile();

    double minn = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxx = Double.MIN_VALUE;

    /*public String[] rMax(){
        String[] temp1;
        String[] temp2;
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that an entry should be an readfile? Why the inheritance between the two classes?

Comment: I have a CSV file, which has a lot of numbers actually i dont know im new and dont know when its suitable to make new classes haha..

Comment: You really want to look into that. Inheritance is **much** more than just putting "extends" behind some class name. A extends B means "A is a B" ... would that make sense in your case? Is an Entry a file? Getting such things is as important as getting to code that "works"!

Comment: that makes sense, you are right

Comment: You are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you move your `openFile()` logic to the **`ReadFile` class constructor** as shown below and this approach will give you two advantages:

(1)`scanner` (which is a mandatory variable of `ReadFile` class) gets initialized inside the class constructor which makes more sense and avoids all `NullPointerException` i.e., someone accidentally calling other methods first before `openFile()` (Always ensure that **all mandatory instance variables i.e., data is being initialized by the constructors**, I strongly suggest make it as a practice and never allow any object being created freely without being the mandatory variables initialized through constructors which will avoid most of the issues).

(2) It will fix your problem **automatically** as you don't need a call to `openFile()` method (well, you don't have that method itself, ReadFile constructor has initialized the scanner).

```
public class ReadFile {
    Scanner x = null;

    public ReadFile() {
        try{
            x = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(
                    "C:\\Users\\Rohan Vidyarthi\\workspace\\Data.csv"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found error");
        }
    }

    public void readFile(){
        //add code
    }

    public void skipFirst(){
        //add code
    }

    public String[] getData(){
        //add code
    }

    public boolean checker(){
        return x.hasNextLine();
    }

    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
  }
```

Just ensure that you don't need to call `openFile()` anymore as shown below:

```
public class Entry extends ReadFile{
    ReadFile e = new ReadFile();//initializes scanner as well

    public String[] readFile() {//add any methods you like here in this like
        return e.readFile();
    }

    double minn = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    double maxx = Double.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

---

> How come I am able to access ReadFile in my Mainn class just fine, but
>   when I try to access it in Entry "e.openFile()" I get an error that
>   says identifier expected.

In Java, invocation of any method call (like your `r.openFile()`) should be done from another method or from constructor or from initializers (static or instance initializer), so the answer is in your `Mainn` class, you are calling the `openFile()` **inside** from `main(String[] args)` method whereas in your `Entry` class your `openFile()` method call is **not wrapped inside** any of the above-mentioned code blocks (i.e., methods, constructors, initializers).

One more important point is that in general when you say **A extends B** in Object Oriented Languages, it means that **A IS-A type of B**, but in your code `Entry extends ReadFile` does not make much sense, so you should avoid that.

Comment: I understood what you said but I still have a question.. As you can see in main, I use a lot of the methods that are defined in ReadFile with no problem. Now If I am trying to use a method, say, getData() in Entry, I have the same error. Why?

Comment: Updated my answer, you can check

Comment: But you follow his doubtful idea of using inheritance. But why should an Entry be a Readfile?

Answer (score 1):

put `e.openFile();` in a method or constructor. You cannot place floating codes outside methods. Any statement can only be used inside the block of codes (i.e. methods, constructors, static initializers)

Comment: Why can't `e.openFile()` be there? How is that "floating"?

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
public class mainn {
    ReadFile r = new ReadFile();
    r.openFile();
    //r.readFile();
    r.skipFirst();
    String x[] = r.getData();
        ...
```

you will receive the same error in `mainn`